# ggplot2 How do I get a count of numbers in column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

```
ggplot(datset, aes(x=Date.received,y=Issue))+geom_dotplot(stat="identity")
```

This is what I have right now and I just want to get a count of "Issue" not grouped by unique identity.

I want to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Maybe `ggplot(datset, aes(x=Date.received))+geom_bar()` will give you the data you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need stat = "count" , so to create bar chart you try

> ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Date.received))+geom_bar( stat = "count")

if line, depending on the format of the Date.received variable, this could work

> ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Date.received))+geom_line( stat = "count")